# Does any thing like CURLOPT_CONNECTIONTIMEOUT exists?

Tags: php, curl

I saw an example using `CURLOPT_CONNECTIONTIMEOUT` but not explaining what it means, is this a valid parameter? I do not see it on PHP man page for `curl_setopt()`.

Answer (score 1):

I believe the option you're looking for is `CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT`.

Edit:

I searched the whole of PHP 5.2.17 and can confirm for you that it doesn't exist. Case closed :)

Comment: I am using `CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT` but was perplexed to see `CURLOPT_CONNECTIONTIMEOUT` in an example, you can see the example here http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.curl-setopt.php#77502

Comment: Perhaps a miss-type? I wouldn't look into it too much.

Comment: Haha it's found in the nusoap library 2010 and just doesn't work :P